# Ruby Sequel (SQlite3) 'SELECT' error

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I'm using a ruby helper to extract data from an SQLite3 database using [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) ORM. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

require_relative 'greekdate'
require 'sequel'

module Pharmacy
    class Open
        def initialize
            db = Sequel.sqlite("../lib/drama.sql")
            @address = db[:addressbook]
            @ov = db[:overnight]
            @grday = GRDay::MDate.new
        end                         

        def display
            data = @address.first(id: get_id()) # ERROR HERE
            p data[:name]
        end

        private
        def get_id
            mod_date = @grday.get[:mod_date]
            @ov.each do |entry|
                return entry[:pharmacy_id] if entry[:date].to_s == mod_date
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I am calling the `display` method. The error I'm getting is:

```
/Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression (Sequel::DatabaseError)
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:263:in `query'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:33:in `log_yield'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `block in synchronize'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:104:in `hold'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:229:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:172:in `_execute'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:122:in `execute'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:794:in `execute'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:356:in `fetch_rows'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:144:in `each'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:584:in `single_record'
    from /Users/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:202:in `first'
    from test.rb:17:in `display'
    from test.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure why this. At first I thought that I should somehow close and re-open the connection, but the error says "**only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression**" and I was getting a single result until yesterday, I see no reason for me to get 2 results since I'm invoking table.**first(id: X)** .

Any ideas and explanations would be more than welcome :-)

Thanks for your time,

PA

Comment: You should put your code in the question, not linked. It will stay on SO longer. As to your question, I believe that if no match is found in `get_id()`, the method will return the query `db[:overnight]` (because that is the behaviour of `each`). This is likely a bug either way, and could be causing your problem

Comment: Usually you would add a `.where` clause to the query, rather than implement the search in Ruby. Could you please include your code in the question?

Comment: Hi Neil, I put the code in the question you are right though. I was using 2 SQLite3 files one for testing and one for production, I mixed them up ending with empty records. I'll just put an exception to notiy be that the DB is empty (no id returned) and I'll be fine!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_id` method returns `@ov` if no entry in `@ov` has the given date, as that is the return value of `@ov.each`.  You probably want something like:

```
def display
    if id = get_id
      data = @address.first(id: id)
      p data[:name]
    end
end

private
def get_id
    mod_date = @grday.get[:mod_date]
    @ov.each do |entry|
        return entry[:pharmacy_id] if entry[:date].to_s == mod_date
    end
    nil
end
```

Note that `display` is a poor choice for a method name, since `Object#display` is already defined by ruby.

Comment: True, I switched that overnight_display to avoid silly conflicts. I added an rescue clause to get a graceful error and understandable error when no entry is matched (which should never happen anyway).